What is $L^2(\mathcal{P}, \nu)$ if $\mathcal{P}$ is the previsible $\sigma$-algebra?
Let $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, \nu)$ be a finite measure space, and let $\mathcal{P}$ be the previsible $\sigma$-algebra on $\Omega \times [0, \infty)$.
The notes I am reading refer to $L^2(\mathcal{P}, \nu)$. What is this space?
I am familiar with the concept of an $L^2$ space, and I understand the definitions in the first line. I'm just not sure how the measure on the product space is supposed to be defined here, and it doesn't seem to be explained anywhere in the notes.

I think it would be more correct to write $L^2(\mathcal P,\nu\otimes\lambda)$ where $\lambda$ denotes the Lebesgue measure on $[0,+\infty)$.
So a family $(X_t:\Omega\to\mathbb R)_{t\ge0}$ belongs to $L^2(\mathcal P,\nu)$ iff it is previsible and is square-integrable in the following sense:
$$
\int_\Omega\left(\int_0^{+\infty}\vert X_t(\omega)\vert^2\,dt\right)\nu(d\omega)<+\infty.
$$

Thanks; I assumed it is with respect to Lebesgue measure, but I was not sure.

Is it in the context of discontinuous stochastic calculus? If yes then it's more often with respect to the measure implied by a previsible quadratic variation rather than the Lebesgue measure.

It is later defined with respect to the quadratic variation of an $L^2$-bounded martingale, but there are no martingales in this part of the notes.
